# System of equations. Find when it has one solution, multiple solutions or no solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a linear algebra class and I'm struggling to understand the solution to the following question:

I have a system of equations given by:

$$x_1 + x_2 + ax_3 = 2\\
2x_1 + x_2 + (2a + 1)x_3 = 5\\
3x_1 + (a-1)x_2 + 2x_3 = b + 2$$

As you can see there is also an a and b in the equations. I am to find a and b such that the system has a single solution. Has no solution and has multiple solution.

So my way to find it was first to perform Gaussian elimination.

$$
M = \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
1 & 1 & a & 2\\
2 & 1 & 2a + 1 & 5\\
3 & a-1 & 2 & b + 2
\end{array}\right)
\xrightarrow{R3 := R3 - 3R1}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
1 & 1 & a & 2\\
2 & 1 & 2a + 1 & 5\\
0 & a-4 & 2 - 3a & b - 4
\end{array}\right)\\
\xrightarrow{R2 := R2 - 2R1}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
1 & 1 & a & 2\\
0 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & a-4 & 2 - 3a & b - 4
\end{array}\right)
$$

And I know that when I have the echolon form there should be n pivots for the equations to have a single solution. So $a - 4$ has to be 0. Which means $a = 4$ I choose $b = -6$ because this is easy to work with.

So a unique solution is easy but I can't find how I can fill in a or b to get no or multiple solutions.

No solutions would require a row to all 0 before the | and a constant after it which I can never get and mutiple solutions requires a row which is all 0 which I also cannot get...

I have no clue how to proceed now so any help is appreciated!

Thank you for reading.

Comment: "And I know that when I have the echolon form there should be n pivots for the equations to have a single solution. So a−4 has to be 0.". Can you explain this reasoning a little? I see no reason why the second sentence should follow from the first...

Comment: @5xum The last row is the only row where I can control when it becomes zero via a. For the matrix to be in echolon form the second column of the last row has to be 0. Which in my case is a - 4.

Comment: **This is completely wrong:** "And I know that when I have the echolon form there should be n pivots for the equations to have a single solution. So a−4 has to be 0.". The condition $a\ne4$ is needed **just to proceed with echelon form creation** (as explained by @5xum). Single solution is guaranteed for $a\ne-1$ as explained in my (ignored) solution. If you don't believe it, put $a=0$ and you will find that the system has unique solution for $x_1,x_2,x_3$. The condition $a\ne4$ should not and will not appear in the final solution of your problem.

Comment: @Oldboy So there is no solution for a=4 ? Can you show this because this seems to be the case for me.

Comment: There is solution for every $a\ne-1$, that's my point. If you insist on Gauss' reduction and echelon form, I'll can edit my answer in a second.

Comment: Please check the improved version of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determinant of the system is:

$$\triangle =\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & a \\ 
2 & 1 & 2a+1 \\ 
3 & a-1 & 2 \\ 
\end{vmatrix}=2+2a$$

The system has unique solution for $\triangle\ne0$ or $a\ne-1$.

For $a=-1$ the system becomes:

$$x_1 + x_2 - x_3 = 2\tag{1}$$
$$2x_1 + x_2 - x_3 = 5\tag{2}$$
$$3x_1 -2 x_2 + 2x_3 = b + 2\tag{3}$$

Subtract (1) from (2) and you get:

$$x_1=3$$

Equations (2) and (3) now become:

$$x_2-x_3=-1$$

$$-2x_2+2x_3=b-7$$

or:

$$-2x_2+2x_3=2$$

$$-2x_2+2x_3=b-7$$

You get infinitely many solutions for $b-7=2$ or for $b=9$. For example, if $x_2=z$ then $x_3=z+1$ (for any $z\in R$) and we already know that $x_1=3$.

For $b\ne9$ there are no solutions.

**EDIT:** If you insist on the echelon form, here is the right order of steps:

$$M = \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
1 & 1 & a & 2\\
2 & 1 & 2a + 1 & 5\\
3 & a-1 & 2 & b + 2
\end{array}\right)
\xrightarrow{R3 := R3 - 3R1}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
1 & 1 & a & 2\\
2 & 1 & 2a + 1 & 5\\
0 & a-4 & 2 - 3a & b - 4
\end{array}\right)\\
\xrightarrow{R2 := R2 - 2R1}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
1 & 1 & a & 2\\
0 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & a-4 & 2 - 3a & b - 4
\end{array}\right)
\xrightarrow{R3 := (a-4)R2 + R3}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
1 & 1 & a & 2\\
0 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & -2 - 2a & a+b - 8
\end{array}\right)
$$

And now, when you are done with the last row, you are ready to make some conclusions (not before it):

Obviously for $-2-2a\ne0$, or $a\ne-1$ you will have a unique solution. For $a=-1$ the last row has all zeros so the system either has infinitely many or no solutions at all. It has to be discussed separately and I already did that in the original version of my answer.

The condition $a=4$ or $a\ne4$ should never be mentioned. It has noting to do with the final solution.

Comment: Yes you are right. This answer is a lot better. Thank you for taking time to make me understand! It didn't occur to me I could multiply with something containing a.

Answer (score 2):

If $a=4$, then yes, you have one unique solution no matter what $b$ is. However, you aren't done yet, and that isn't the only possibility for a unique solution!

You examined all possibilities when $a=4$ (there's only one), now you must continue and analyse all other possibilities. From here on, you can assume that $a\neq 4$, so you can divide the final row $R_3$ by $a-4$ and get $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & \frac{2-3a}{a-4} & | & \frac{b-4}{a-4}\end{pmatrix}$$ as your final row.

Then, continue creating the echelon form.

Comment: I disagree with the "style" of this answer. Now John believes that $a=4$ is the right condition for a unique solution. While in fact there is a unique solution for $a\ne1$.

Comment: @Oldboy that all depends on how he interprets my sentence "However, you aren't done yet, and **that isn't the only possibility for a unique solution**!"

Comment: And one should NEVER multiply the third row with $\frac1{a-4}$. That just makes things complicated and forces you to treat $a=4$ as a special case. The right approach is to multiply the second row with $(a-4)$ and add it to the third row. No special cases.