# 3x3 system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, determinant

I have the following system of equations:
\begin{equation}
x+y+kz = 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x+ky+z = 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
kx+y+z =1
\end{equation}

where $x,y,z \in \mathbf{R}$.

For what values of $k \in \mathbf{R} $ 
i) the system has a single solution 
ii) the system has multiple solutions
iii) the system has no solution

Can anyone help with that please?

I wrote the above system in a matrix form:

\begin{equation*}

\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 1 & k & 1 \\
1 & k & 1 & 1\\
k & 1 & 1 & 1
 \end{array}

\end{equation*}

I am not sure how to proceed.. If I subtract the second row from the first (1)-(2) I have the following:

\begin{equation*}

\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 1 & k & 1 \\
0 & 1-k & k-1 & 0\\
k & 1 & 1 & 1
 \end{array}

\end{equation*}

Then if I subtract the third row from the first row (1)-(3):
\begin{equation*}

\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 1 & k & 1 \\
0 & 1-k & k-1 & 0\\
1-k & 0 & k-1 & 0
 \end{array}

\end{equation*}

Comment: Yes, of course! Show please your attempts.

Comment: I edited my first post to see how I started to work out the above system.

Comment: I think, it's better to use the Cramer's rule. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule See now.

Comment: In principle, this is duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2921226/265466 and many others on this site. Look through the handy list of related questions at right and you’ll find several examples of similar problems.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I mostly agree, with the caveat that when all of the determinants vanish, you have to investigate further. Unlike the $2\times2$ case, for a $3\times3$ system you can’t immediately conclude that the system is indeterminate in that situation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Incompatible_and_indeterminate_cases for an example of an incompatible system for which all of the determinants vanish.

Comment: @amd See my post. This solution takes five minutes maximum. I am sure that you know, how to evaluate the determinant $3X3$ quickly.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg You’re missing my point. In the $k=1$ case, you need to do just a bit more besides noting that all of the determinants vanish to conclude that there’s an infinite number of solutions. (Yes, the extra work in this case is trivial.) Your answer doesn’t reflect that at all.

Comment: @amd But it's really trivial for $k=1$. After evaluating of determinants we know also that this value ($k=1$) is an unique value for ii)

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/930252/265466.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Michael Rozenberg’s suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3620835/265466) to use Cramer’s rule is a good one because the determinants are all very easy to compute. However, if you must proceed via row-reduction, you need to proceed systematically: your goal should be to end up with all zeros below each pivot. You also need to be a bit careful about the operations that you perform. The operation $R_n\to cR_n+R_m$, which is what you did for your second step, isn’t an *elementary* row operation, and doing thing like this can cause problems for you in other calculations, such as computing the determinant of a matrix. This is really a combination of two elementary operations: multiply a row by a constant and add one row to another.

Anyway, with the goal of zeroing out everything below the $1$ in the upper-left corner, you should add $-k$ times the first row the the third to obtain $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&k&1\\0&k-1&1-k&0\\0&1-k&1-k^2&1-k\end{array}\right].$$ At this point, it should be obvious that when $k=1$, the last two rows are both zero, so there’s an infinite number of solutions in that case. We continue with the row reduction by adding the second row to the third: $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&k&1\\0&k-1&1-k&0\\0&0&2-k-k^2&1-k\end{array}\right].$$ Now examine the last row to determine which values of $k$ result in none, one or an infinite number of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\Delta=\left|\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1 & k\\1 & k & 1\\ k & 1 & 1 \end{array}\right)\right|=-k^3+3k-2=-(k+2)(k-1)^2,$$
$$\Delta_x=\left|\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1 & k\\1 & k & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{array}\right)\right|=-(k-1)^2,$$

$$\Delta_y=\left|\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1 & k\\1 & 1 & 1\\ k & 1 & 1 \end{array}\right)\right|=-(k-1)^2,$$
$$\Delta_z=\left|\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1 & 1\\1 & k & 1\\ k & 1 & 1 \end{array}\right)\right|=-(k-1)^2,$$ which gives the answer:

i) $k\neq-2$ and $k\neq1$;

ii) $k=1$;

iii) $k=-2$.

Comment: Using Cramer's rule when I calculated the determinant I found: $3k -k^3-2$. Also what $\Delta_x, \Delta_y, \Delta_z$ mean?

Comment: @Gina Wait please. I'll explain this point,

Comment: Oki, I was trying to convert the initial matrix to identity matrix. Because this is what we've been taught..

Comment: How did you decide that there’s an infinite number of solutions when $k=1$? For a $3\times3$ system, you can’t conclude this from only the fact that all of the determinants vanish. For example, all of the determinants also vanish in the system $x+y+z=1$, $x+y+z=2$, $x+y+z=3$, but that system obviously doesn’t have an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @amd  In our problem for $k=1$  we got $\Delta_x=\Delta_y=\Delta_z=\Delta=0$. Did you get the same result for your system? If so, we can substitute $k=1$ in the original system.

Comment: Yes. My point once again is that all of the determinants’ vanishing isn’t a sufficient condition for a $3\times3$ system to have an infinite number of solutions, as my counterexample shows. After setting $k=1$ in the system it’s of course obvious that there’s an infinite number of solutions, but that extra step is needed.

Comment: @amd Yes, I agree. It's an important point,